# Throw in try, catch, finally - weird behavior?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I don't understand why this:

```
try {
    throw 'err1';
} catch {
    throw 'err2';
} finally {
    throw 'err3';
}
```

Gives me this:

```
$ node try.js

/try.js:6
    throw 'err3';
    ^
err3
```

I would suspect, that I should get `err2`. I know that `finally {}` is always executed, whether `try {}` succeeded or not, but why exception from `finally {}` is returned before exception in `catch {}`?

Comment: That's the way the language is defined to work. If the `finally` clause throws an exception, then that's the result of the whole construction.

Comment: It can only return 1 exception, and seen as finally, means finally, that's the one that wins.  You can always handle the error again inside the catch,.  JS can handle nested exception's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the behaviour as defined by the [ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-try-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> TryStatement : `try Block` `Catch` `Finally`
>
> 1. Let `B` be the result of evaluating Block.
> 2. If `B.[[type]]` is throw, then
>
>    - Let `C` be CatchClauseEvaluation of Catch with parameter `B.[[value]]`.
> 3. Else `B.[[type]]` is not throw, let `C` be `B`.
> 4. Let `F` be the result of evaluating Finally.
> 5. If `F.[[type]]` is normal, let `F` be `C`.
> 6. If `F.[[type]]` is return, or `F.[[type]]` is throw, return `Completion(F)`.
>
> [...]

This might be non-trivial to read. But the gist of it is that the result of the `catch` block is assigned to `C`. But if the `finally` returns anything or `throws`, `C` is ignored and the result of the `finally` is returned instead.

Answer (score 0):

A `throw` isn't an instantaneous thing. It's easy to feel like it when you don't have a `finally` block but the `finally` has the ability to change your `throw` (it can also change your return value!) and the value isn't handled until the function actually ends. (with some exceptions for thread termination, etc)